# DIV 100% height with footer and header, dynamic

Tags: html, css, height

I've searched now for hours for a good solution of the 100% height div problem. I tried now different code, but some of them are not really helpful (in my case) because of I need a responsive and IE8+ support solution. So some helpful tags, like the 'calc()' function or 'flexbox' are not valid.

I have created a [sample page](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oYJVrW), to show you the problem. The footer should be on the bottom of the current size of the window. Both content divs should have the full height of the current content screen and there houldn't be any scrollbar, as long as the content goes over the current screen. The Footer shouldn't be fixed and should move "down", if the content grows over the current screen height.

My page is responsive and build with Bootstrap 3. So there are some more rows and columns, but the basic build is like shown below.

The current page is build like:

```
<div id="page">
  <div id="header">
    My menu 
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="" id="content_left">
      Some content here ...
    </div>
    <div id="content_right">
      Some content there ...
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    My footer
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body 
{
  display: block;
  min-height:100%; 
  height: 100%;
  padding:0; 
  margin:0;
}

#page
{
  margin: auto;
  max-width:500px;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #333;
}

#header
{
  padding: 20px;
  background: #FF0;
}

#footer
{
  padding: 20px;
  background: #F0F;
  clear: both;
}

#content_left
{
  background: #0F0;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

#content_right
{
  background: #0FF;
  width: 65%;
  float: left;
}

#content_left, #content_right
{
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Sorry for that many conditions, but it is the environment I have to work with. (-;

Best regards,
SKiD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for you advice, but I have solved the problem.
I've made a new CodepenIO inclusive the Bootstrap 3 framework.

For the solution itself I have excluded the footer out of the wrapper. Means the content of the main container is the wrapper DIV (which includes all content) and the footer DIV (which includes the footer). For the bottom elements of the wrapper I added a padding-bottom attribute and for the footer itself a minus margin-top attribute which equals the height of the footer. So the footer moves up, if the content does not cause a pagebreak and the footer moves down if there is to much content. The solution itself you can find [**HERE**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JbzEBj).

The **HTML** looks like the following:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="" id="wrapper">
    <div class="row" id="header">
      <div class="">My menu</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="content">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4" id="content_left">
        Some content here ...
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8" id="content_right">
        Some content there...
      </div>
    </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="footer">
    <div>My footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And **CSS**:

```
html,body
{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.container 
{
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  min-height:100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  background: #333;
}

#wrapper
{
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: #A00;
}

.content
{
  background: #A00;
}

#header 
{
  padding: 20px;
  background: #FF0;
}

#footer 
{
  clear: both;
  background: #F0F;
  min-height: 20px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

#content_left 
{
  background: #0F0;
}

#content_right 
{
  background: #0FF;
}

#content_left,
#content_right 
{
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Thank you very much for you help! (-:

Comment: It is wonderful but how can fit it with header and footer design with another animation of it?

Answer (score 0):

you can consider doing it as the following

check this snippet

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
#page {
  margin: auto;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background: #333;
}
#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  background: #A00;
}
#header {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #FF0;
}
#content_left {
  display: table-cell;
  background: #0F0;
  width: 25%;
}
#content_right {
  display: table-cell;
  background: #0FF;
  width: 75%;
}
#content_left,
#content_right {
  padding: 10px;
}
#footer {
  background: orange;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
      My menu
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <div class="" id="content_left">
        Some content here ...
      </div>
      <div id="content_right">
        <br />Some content there ...
        <br />Some content there ...
        <br />Some content there ...
        <br />Some content there ...
        <br />Some content there ...
        <br />Some content there ...
        <br />Some content there ...
        <br />Some content there ...
        <br />Some content there ...
        <br />Some content there ...
        <br />Some content there ...
        <br />Some content there ...
        <br />Some content there.
        <br />Some content there.
        <br />Some content there.

        <br />Some content there ...
        <br />Some content there.
        <br />Some content there.
        <br />Some content there ...
        <br />Some content there.
        <br />Some content there ...
        <br />Some content there.
        <br />Some content there ...
        <br />Some content there.
        <br />Some content there ...
        <br />Some content there.
        <br />Some content there ...
        <br />Some content there.
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      My footer
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It's a good start, but the website isn't scaling up to 100% height, if there is less content. Or did I miss something?

Comment: modified the snippet...check now is this what you are looking for

Comment: The problem of "vh" is, that it is not supported from IE8. Supported is only from IE10+. But to make a little more clear, what I exactly want I have created a [PICTURE](https://s29.postimg.org/u0dojwwnr/100percent_height.jpg) you can take a look at. The thing is, without so much content (which is not filling the complete box) the footer is on the bottom. As soon as there is enough content, the footer moves down with the content and there will also appear a scrollbar.

Comment: so footer should always be bottom and when there is large content does div needs to have scroll bar?

Comment: yes vh does not work in ie10 ,but the same can be achieved using vmin .check this snippet http://codepen.io/sahithiK/pen/GNPaRb and let me know if this what you want

Comment: The problem stays the same. Browser support only from IE9+ and the footer isn't on the bottom of the page with less content. I have solved the problem with the following : [Take a look.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aBXOVR). The only problem is, that the background doesn't scale up with the content itself. When there is less content (no site break) then it is all fine. As soon as the content goes over the page, footer moves down (like I wanted), but the background doesn't scale up (normally a background-picture with repeat-y property, here only background-color).

Comment: Oh I guess I only had to add display:table and display:table-cell attributes and now it works like it should be. More I know after testing!

Comment: Modified the code snippet..Let us know if this is what you are looking for